# Keycloak unable to login - removed totp credentials

Tags: keycloak

In keycloak master realm we had 2 credentials for admin user, one is password and another is totp. I have accidentally deleted the totp credentials. Now when I am trying to login after username/password it asks for authenticator and fails with error "Invalid authenticator code". Please help

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the browser login flow (which I assume you're referring to) there are usually  other login flows available which you could try to use to log in. For example, are you able to use the password reset flow? Alternatively, have you set up federation login?

If there are no alternative ways to log in, you can examine your keycloak configuration for the master username / password and try logging in with that. If you're saying you added 2-factor to the master username/password and now you can't log in, I do not know how to proceed.

I suppose you could try creating a DB backup and then restoring the backup to a separate DB; and then spinning up a new Keycloak instance and connecting to that DB. I'm not sure if that would work though.

Comment: Thanks Gregory Ledray. I have restored using a backup to a state before this and it is working. Thanks for the suggestion